# React Components - Moving from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am rewriting React app to typescript. When I change code to tsx I get errors about not specified types in child javascript component.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Comp1 from '../Comp1'

interface props {
  name: string
}

const Comp: React.SFC<props> = ({ name }) => (
  <div>
    <div>name prop: {name}</div>
    <Comp1 name={name} /> // error: TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Connector> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &...'.
  </div>
)

export default Comp
```

Is there any way to skip these errors checking for javascript components, so I can build my app and merge changes component by component, not the whole app at once?

Comment: In this case it looks like the React type definitions aren't found, so the compiler doesn't know that a React Component has a name. For your own code, you can use `any` as the type for everything,, or allow `implicitAny` in tsconfig. There's also an option to allow JS in tsconfig. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I know that it doesn't know the name in Comp1, but it's javascript component, I want to rewrite it to typescript in separate branch, but I can't, because typescript doesn't build. `noInplictAny` nor `allowJS` didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried renaming all .js components to .ts ? (If you allow `implicit any` then the TS code should look exactly the same as JS)